# Doctrine2 - How to limit @OneToMany mapping size?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I was wondering if there exists any way to set a constraint on the size of a `@OneToMany` relation in Doctrine2.

Let's say I have 2 classes: `User` and `Toy`:

```
class User{
    ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Toy", mappedBy="user")
     */
    public $toys;
    ...
}
class Toy{
    ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="toys")
     */
    public $user;
    ...
}
```

I would like to force each user to have at most 3 toys. Do you know if there is a way to achieve this by using any Doctrine2 annotation?

If it is not possible through annotations, how would you do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class User {
 [..]
 public function addToy (Toy $toy)
 {
   if(count($this->toys) >= 3 && !$this->toys->contains($toy)) {
     throw new User\ToyLimitExceededException(
       'At most 3 toys are allowed per user, tried to add another!'
     );
   }
   $this->toys->add($toy);
   $toy->setUser($this);
   return $this;
 }
 [..]
}
```

Comment: I like this way and I think it is actually the most effective. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: if $this->toys already contains $toy wouldn't it add it twice because of the second condition in the if statement? the add() function is not very smart and doesn't verify if it's already there.